# Bottom Navigation View gets Shrinked Down till Recycler view is loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, bottomnavigationview

I have made an app with bottom navigation view with home, offers, and favorite tabs
when I am changing from home fragment to any other fragment, the bottom navigation view gets shrunk down as shown in the image, I tried changing layout width, height and converting coordinator layout to linear layout but it didn't help.
The problem is occurring when I'm switching from home to any other tab only.

Layout File
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />



</LinearLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    tools:context="com.naturaldeveloper.halfdeals.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.naturaldeveloper.halfdeals.activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm replacing the content with the fragments.

while switching to other tabs 
shrinking issue[image]

when in the home tab
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?